# Is there a way to store "extended enum" with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, enums

Is there a way to store "extended enum" with JPA ?
I'm working with abstract object in my spring boot project and my base object can have multiple states. The object extending it can have the base state but also other specific states. You can't extend `enum` in Java, so my I first tought of using an `interface` with a default method `isCommon` to discriminate between my common enum values and my extended enum values in my services.
However I can't use the annotation `@Enumerated` on my property anymore. Is there a way to  make it work or another pattern I could use ?
A small code sample to provide some context :

```java
@Entity
abstract class AbstractFoo {
   public StateInterface state;
}

@Entity
class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {

}

@Service
class ConcreteFooService {
    public boolean isCommonState(ConcreteFoo foo) {
        return foo.state.isCommon();
    }
}

interface StateInterface {
   default boolean isCommon() {
       return false;
   }
}

enum CommonState extends StateInterface {
   BEGIN, END;
   
   @Override
   boolean isCommon() {
      return true;
   }
}

enum SpecificState extends StateInterface {
    MIDDLE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you using the following Enum instead:

```java
enum State {
    BEGIN(true), MIDDLE(false), END(true);

    private final boolean common;

    State(boolean common) {
        this.common = common;
    }

    public boolean isCommon() {
       return common;
    }
}
```

For your use case, this is the best I can think of.

Comment: Yes but it breaks the extensibility of my package! I want to be able to add and remove states without touching the core of my application

Comment: As you learned with your tries if you use an Interface to emulate Enum extensibility you will not be able to use `@Enumerated` JPA-related annotation. So you will need to compromise. Either you have extensible Enums and implement some black magic to make them work with JPA seamlessly **OR** you have a single Enum with an additional parameter that you will need to change whenever needed and simply use `@Enumerated` to have it handled by JPA. It is your decision now.